# OpenGL: How to map point inside frustrum to normal device coordinates (NDC)?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, frustum, clipping, projection-matrix

I read this article http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html.
It's explain how calculate projection matrix coefficients.
But I completely can't understand how author perform mapping from frustrum to NDC.

[image]

Why x<sub>n</sub> perpendicular to x<sub>p</sub>? I can't imagine it. Maybe someone can explain it? Or share useful source.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found answer. I inattentively read article.

> **"Next, we map xp and yp to xn and yn of NDC with linear relationship."**

So, xn is linear function from xp. (http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/linear-equations.html)
And goal is find value of xn in [-1, 1] range.

Anyway I didn't understand how author find bottom projection row W (0,0,-1,0).

Comment: The bottom row is necessary to flip the z-axis between view-space and clip-space. This is illustrated in the [following diagram](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/images/Ex01_Projection.png). See how Z points in a different direction pre- and post-projection? Everything else about that diagram is wrong though =P _That's Direct3D's NDC and screen-space convention._